# How to set up a countup timer only when the button press?

Tags: android

I am implementing a countup timer and I follow an example from StackoverFlow.
In my version, I will press the Begin button to start counting and the Stop button to stop.
But the problem is that the counting start immediately after i enter the activity.
Any idea how to make it the way i want?

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity
{
    Button beginRecordingButton;
    TextView timer;
    long startTime;
    long countup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startactivity);
        beginRecordingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BeginRecording);
        timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        final Chronometer stopwatch = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chrono);
        startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        stopwatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(listener);


        beginRecordingButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            int counter = 0;


            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                if (counter % 2 == 0)
                {


                    stopwatch.start();
                    beginRecordingButton.setText("Stop");
                }
                if (counter % 2 == 1)
                {

                    stopwatch.stop();
                    beginRecordingButton.setText("Begin");
                }
                counter++;  //counter is used for knowing it is stop or begin

            }
        });
    }

    private OnChronometerTickListener listener = new OnChronometerTickListener()
    {

        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer)
        {
            String text;
            countup = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase())/1000;
            if(countup%60<10)
            {
                 text = (countup/60) + ":0" + (countup%60);
            }
            else
            {
                 text = (countup/60) + ":" + (countup%60);
            }

            timer.setText(text);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution by doing follow:

```
long test;

test = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stopwatch.getBase())/1000;
Log.i(TAG, = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000 - test;

basically String.valueOf(test));
stopwatch.start();
```

countup the idea is to subtract the passing time if i press the start button so it goes from 0